# NullPointerException when declaring semaphores in Java?

Tags: java, exception, concurrency, nullpointerexception, semaphore

I get a`NullPointerException` when I try to run this code:

```
private static Semaphore[] trackSemas;

for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            trackSemas[i] = new Semaphore(1,true);
        }
```

Why doesn't this bit of code get a NullPointerException?

Comment: `trackSemas` is probably not initialized anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the `trackSemas` array:

```
private static Semaphore[] trackSemas = new Semaphore[9];
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.